# Get caption from unattached images in gallery?

Tags: gallery

I've created a slideshow that automatically populates with images included in a post's gallery, and I want to display each image's 'caption' field as well.

I'm currently using `get_post_gallery_images` to loop through the relevant images, but that only returns an array of the image's URL's, and I need the caption data. The `$counter` and `$sizes` variables are some extra modifiers for handling things with Flexslider, but they're not essential to looping through the images.

```
   function get_images($post_id) {
   global $post;

  if( has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) ) {
      $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID ); // Returns array or URLs
      $counter = -1;
      $sizes = ["-300x200", "-200x300"]; // Search for medium suffixes from gallery thumbs

      // Loop through each image in each gallery
      foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

          $counter++;
          $attachment = get_post($image);

          echo '<li>';
          echo '<img src=" ' . str_replace($sizes, '', $image) . '"';
          echo ' alt="';
          echo '" data-slide="';
          echo $counter;
          echo '" />';
          echo '</li><!--end slide-->';
          echo '<p class="slide-caption">';
          echo '</p>';
      } // End for each
  } // End if

} // End function
```

I've found methods using `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` but I think that requires having the images attached to the post itself. I'd like to grab images from the **gallery** (whether or not the images are attached to this particular post) because I want the client to be able to upload via the media library without worrying about attachments. Any ideas on how to accomplish this, or do I just need to accept that attachments are necessary?

**Updated code based on answer** — For anyone else trying to build a Flexslider slideshow from a gallery of thumbnails... This includes extra variables to count each image and assign it a `data-slide` number (which Flexslider uses for programatic linking). The answer below returns thumbnail images or whatever size the gallery is using, so I figured out a way to parse the URL and remove the size declaration to return the full size images.

```
// GALLERY WITH CAPTIONS
function slider_from_gallery($post_id) {
        if (
          $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false ) ) :
              $img_ids = explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] );
              $counter = -1;
            /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
            foreach(
              $gallery['src'] as $key => $src ) : ?>

                <li>
                  <?php
                  $image_post = get_post( $img_ids[ $key ] );
                  $counter++; // Increase for each image, gets passed to data-slide below
                  $new_src = substr($src, 0, strrpos( $src, '-')) . '.jpg'; // Get full size by finding last occurance of - and adding .jpg
                   ?>
                  <img src="<?php echo $new_src; ?>" class="slide-image" alt="Gallery image" data-slide="<?php echo $counter ?>" />
                  <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo $image_post->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                </li>

            <?php endforeach;
        endif;
} //End function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'gallery', 
        'posts_per_page' => 100 ) 
            ); 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        if ( $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false ) ) :

            $img_ids = explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] );
            /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
            foreach( $gallery['src'] as $key => $src ) : ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="my-custom-class" alt="Gallery image" />
                <?php
                    $image_post = get_post( $img_ids[ $key ] ); ?>
                    <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $image_post->post_excerpt; ?></p>

            <?php endforeach;
        endif;

 endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to read up on some of the php to understand exactly what's going on here but this does work.